# Apple Watch Complication extension

Tags: ios, swift2, apple-watch-complication

I'm creating a Complication for Apple Watch and I've came across a doubt.

For now, I've set an Array of 5 entries for the timeline, and everything is working correctly.
my question goes, what happens when the request returns nil, like after the 5 entries were displayed?

Does the Watch refreshes itself and executes all of the delegate methods again to populate the entries, or does it stops working because it hasn't more information to display since the 5 entries were displayed already?

If so, is there any way of adding another entry to the end of the array itself? When the first entry of the array has passed is there a way for me to append a new one to the end of it, so I'd get always 5 entries to display and the app wouldn't run out of information to display?

It could sound confusing, but I hope you'd get what I meant to say, hope my English is understandable.

Kind regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the flow for updating complication data for Apple Watch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973035/what-is-the-flow-for-updating-complication-data-for-apple-watch)

Comment: You're right, the link you've shared it's kinda what I was looking for. Thx.