# Refresh watchos app based on internet connectivity

Tags: swift, swift3, watchkit, watchos-3

I have found a great description of the process for refreshing both the watchapp UI and its complications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37972842/3715676). That works for me, even though sometimes the UI is only updated when I actually bring the app to the foreground (but that's another issue).

what I have been doing so far is this:

1 - I schedule a background refresh;

2 - When the background refresh task is called, I schedule a background downloadTask;

3 - After completion, the downloadTask call its delegate method (`didFinishDownloadingTo`), where I call another method to update the UI, reload my complications with new data and to schedule a snapshot refresh and another background refresh.

This is almost working fine (with the ocasional problem I mentioned above). But I put my watch on flight mode sometimes. What happens here is that the error delegate method is called, and so I schedule another app refresh for about 1 hour. If still in flight mode, it will request another refresh in one hour, and so on.

The problem with this approach is that when I turn off the flight mode, the app takes a long time to update its UI, depending on when the next update is scheduled.

Can someone suggest a better approach to get new data as soon as one gets internet connectivity back?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (watchOS 3.2) there is no framework in watchOS that could tell you when the device connects to the internet. However, you could leverage the [Reachability framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/systemconfiguration/scnetworkreachability-g7d) in your iOS app and use the WatchConnectivity framework to signal your Watch app when it can refresh its UI.