# TableView setup gets called before didReceiveUserInfo

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, watchkit, watchos-2

My table keeps ending up empty because `didRecieveUserInfo` isn't called until after `doTable()` gets called.

*I'm getting all the correct data in `didRecieveUserInfo`, but my app doesn't know that because `didRecieveUserInfo` isn't getting called until after the table is already set up.*

Any ideas? I feel like it must be something simple, here is my code:

**`ExtensionDelegate`:**

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
        let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()
    }
}

func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {


    if let tCValue = userInfo["Tr"] as? String, let mValue = userInfo["Mp"] as? String {

        receivedData.append(["Tr" : tCValue , "Mp" : mValue])
        evn.append(Evnt(dataDictionary: ["Tr" : tCValue , "Mp" : mValue]))

    } else {
        // None
    }

}
```

**`InterfaceController`:**

```
override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
    doTable()
}

func doTable() {

    if WCSession.defaultSession().reachable == true {

    // SO
    let myDelegate = WKExtension.sharedExtension().delegate as! ExtensionDelegate
    let evM = myDelegate.evn

    self.rowTable.setNumberOfRows(evM.count, withRowType: "rows")


    for (index, evt) in evM.enumerate() {

        if let row = rowTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as? TableRowController {

            row.mLabel.setText(evt.maT)

        } else {
          // None  
        }
    }

    }
    else {
          // None  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the WCSession Delegate in the Interfacecontroller and call the doTable() after you receive your data

Comment: That's what I was doing before, but I was trying to move a lot of the logic out of the `InterfaceController` into the `ExtensionDelegate` so that it could be accessed by the `ComplicationController`, or will it not matter if the WCSessionDelegate is in the `InterfaceController` when it concerns the Complication Controller?  Thanks!

Comment: I think it must be in the InterfaceController. You can check this detailed answer on so:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214868/get-data-to-complication-extensiondelegate-not-called